# Error trying to confirm Brownie was installed successfully

Tags: terminal, chainlink, brownie

After installing dependencies I typed "brownie" to make sure that everything was installed successfully but instead I got an error. (Any comments/help appreciated)Will attach the code below:

```
injusstice@Justices-MacBook-Pro ~ % brownie
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/injusstice/.local/bin/brownie", line 5, in <module>
    from brownie._cli.__main__ import main
  File "/Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from brownie.project import compile_source, run
  File "/Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/project/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .main import (  # NOQA 401
  File "/Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/project/main.py", line 44, in <module>
    from brownie.network import web3
  File "/Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/network/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .account import Accounts
  File "/Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/network/account.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .rpc import Rpc
  File "/Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/network/rpc/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from brownie.network.state import Chain
  File "/Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/network/state.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .transaction import TransactionReceipt
  File "/Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/brownie/network/transaction.py", line 15, in <module>
    import black
  File "/Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/black/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    import regex as re
  File "/Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .regex import *
  File "/Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/regex.py", line 419, in <module>
    import regex._regex_core as _regex_core
  File "/Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/_regex_core.py", line 21, in <module>
    import regex._regex as _regex
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so: code signature in (/Users/injusstice/.local/pipx/venvs/eth-brownie/lib/python3.8/site-packages/regex/_regex.cpython-38-darwin.so) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: Trying to load an unsigned library
```

Comment: Can you add the steps you took to reach this point?

Comment: Yes tonight i'll start the process over and share all the steps with the code, thanks for replying!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.